# Why this magit process happens after pushing some changes to a remote repository? How to avoid it?

Tags: magit, git, networking

After pushing some changes to a remote repository using magit, Emacs shows this process running:

```
git-credenti... 72390   run      *git-creden... /dev/pts/1   git credential-cache--daemon /home/pedro/.git-credential-cache/socket
```

It seems to be connected to the fact that I typed my username and password before doing the push.

Why does this happen?

How to fix it? Killing the buffer?

After using `C-x C-b` (list buffer), I was not able to press `D` to execute the deletion with `X` later. It was necessary to kill it with `C-x k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process provides the [credential cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache), so that you don't have to enter your password each time you pull, push or other otherwise access that remote.

If you don't need the cache anymore, you can kill the process in the usual way, for example from the `list-processes` buffer, or with the `kill-process` function. Magit doesn't currently offer a command to directly kill the credential cache daemon process.

If you don't want credentials to be cached, you can disable this altogether by setting [`magit-credential-cache-daemon-socket`](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/v3.1.1/lisp/magit-process.el#L118) (with `setq` or via Customize).